Is it advantegeous to create a new page targeting a high-impression, low-click keyword of another page?
Let's say Page A of a website has a high-impression, low-click Keyword K. The reason for the low click is that the content of Page A doesn't match the intent of K.
Now the website plans to add a new page Page B, which is optimized for Keyword K and matches the intent of Keyword K. Does Page B come with an natural advantage in getting a good ranking in search results, compared in adding this new page B to a different site?

It depends but logically this should be the case. Will take some time for algos to determine this.
CTR is important here to shift the needle. If you're confident in introducing an improved seo title that increases ctr and matches intent then average user engagement time should be higher.
Overall the algo should reward this positively with higher rankings.

Overall, as the previous author mentioned, the logic works exactly that way.
But a clarification: CTR is influenced not by the page content itself, but by the meta tag content. This is what directly affects how people click on your site in the SERP.
As for the advantage, it still depends on the domain's age and overall ranking.
To summarize: in your case, this is a perfectly logical and justified decision. If you create this page on an existing site, it will have a better chance of ranking well due to the site's authority and history.

Thanks for the answer. Is the site authority associated with the keyword? I'm a bit puzzled because some sources say that keywords are only associated with pages.

Keyword with authority no, but ranking yes.
That is, a site with a better domain is more likely to get positions faster by creating a new page with this keyword than a younger site that does not yet have a domain ranking.
